# Laravel token mismatch on new https server

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

I made a project in laravel on a server. Then switched to another server and domain with ssl certificate.

I get **Token mismatch** on most of the actions.

I changed all the names, I have in `<head>`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In my javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

In my `.env` I have:

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
```

In `sessions.php`:

```
'domain' => 'https://www.example.com,
'secure' => false,
```

Response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges   
bytes
Cache-Control   
no-cache, private
Content-Encoding    
gzip
Content-Type    
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    
Fri, 07 Oct 2016 09:10:10 GMT
Server  
LiteSpeed
Set-Cookie  
  laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImZEMW0rQlA4bVR0ZzV0YzlPYStRRUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUmlTdTExU210RVF1bVhSQVc0Vjl2
ZjgzbEF3czAxdWRcL3B2cVAwWlA4Y1B4T1RWUkhNVm1sc3JxT3lsc08yKzV5V2R4c3hMcXVOaDVrY1wvVWVvQUt0QT09IiwibWFjIjoiNWFhNTNhNDdmNTg0NDNhZjM0OTQyMDU3NTY1ZWU4ZTEwNDA5ZThjN2JlMjU5ZjgxZWY3NmRiZjQzNWE1MzlkMCJ9
; path=/; domain=https://www.example.com; httponly
Vary    
Accept-Encoding
X-Firefox-Spdy  
h2
```

Request headers:

```
Content-Type    
multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------18211321129586
Cookie  
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkFPZkdVMHRCdHo1NXVzVDZ5WW9cL3FRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InlYTStsSFZsVXdLNGhEQ1RGSjBRTzZHU
kE4SThoWWhKN0l6Y0xGcm1CTE9rM2RvZ1FTV0ZwNmhZd0pUd1JVcjRFQk5BUHpCM1lVMWxRZWNRcXlCeVFBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIwNzc3YWM5Y2U0YzljNzI3YjhhNmRjYjM3YzM1NTFiZDEwMmFjYTA4ODYzM2RkMWZkN2MwNmVmZWVlMmE5ZjAwIn0
%3D
```

I uploaded an image with them here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fws3dsor1fib6ea/Untitled.png

Well, for example I have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.example.com/auth" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="loginForm" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="_token" value="xevbyX59z691oQoatyV0Kn5WQP2mHX16zpJc9T6" type="hidden">
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Somehow problem solved:

I created a new project and copy pasted the routes, views controllers and everything else.

**I still got the token mismatch when I changed the session lifetime to 0 from the default 120.** . But I left it at some value greater than 0 and now I dont get the token mismatch anymore.

Comment: Can you post your headers in the request that fails?

Comment: Well, in your heders I don't see the csrf token to be sent. Are you sure you have included `$.ajaxSetup` **before** your `$.ajax` requests?

Comment: What you have editted and included as "Request headers" are the response headers?

Comment: I made a mistake, I corrected it now, those are the correct request and response headers. The XSRF TOKEN is in the request but not in the response ones

Comment: The `XSRF` token **is** in the response headers. The `CSRF` token should be in your **request** headers. There's something fishy about all of this. Can you confirm you have included the information correctly?

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework like Angular? Also `form#loginForm` is submitted via `$.ajax`?

Comment: I use jQuery and yes, it is submitted via $.ajax